# Picture is not showing in jsp page

Tags: jsp

My image is not showing in JSP page.I am using Eclipse.I have created a folder 'img' in WEB-INF folder,then saved the picture in this and the code in jsp page is `<img alt="img/home.jpg" height="100" width="100">`.Why the picture is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

WEB-INF is not publicly available.  The servlet container protects this directory in your web app, and no resources will be served directly from this directory.  `img/home.jpg` will be relative to the directory of the current page.  Try moving the img folder to the top level of your web app (the same level as WEB-INF).  Then use the absolute path in your img tag: `/img/home.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `img` folder at the same level as `WEB-INF`.
Keep static files like `HTML`, `image`, `stylesheet`, `javascript`, etc. under the web root, not inside WEB-INF because it is not accessible.

After doing this,Change your `img` tag like this

```
<img alt="/img/home.jpg" height="100" width="100">
```

### See Also

- [Folder structure in web application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/gexap.html)